# Compare floats in javascript and change the color of the highest

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a HTML table, made in php with the values in my database.

I want to get the highest price and change the color of this one (same for the smallest price). 
But in my script I think there is a problem in my comparison because it misses 1/2 value. (my english is not really good so I hope you'll understand with the code)

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Rang</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prix(€)</th>
        <th >Description</th>
        <th>Précisions d'achat</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        $i=1;
        while($donnees = $resultPop->fetch()){
            echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$i.'</td>
            <td><a href="'.$donnees['POP_LINK'].'">'.$donnees['POP_NOM'].'</a></td>
            <td class="prix">'.$donnees['POP_PRIX'].'</td>
            <td>'.$donnees['POP_DESCRIPTION'].'</td>
            <td>'.$donnees['POP_PRECISION'].'</td>
            </tr>';
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
    </table>
    <script>
        var prix = new Array;
        prix[0] = document.getElementsByClassName('prix');
        var i = 0;
        var cheapest = 0;
        while(i< 7){
            console.log(i);
            if (Number(prix[0][i].innerHTML) > Number(prix[0][i+1].innerHTML)){
                cheapest = prix[0][i+1];
                console.log(cheapest.innerHTML);
            }
            i++;
        }
        cheapest.style.color = 'red';
    </script>
```

Or I thought maybe doing a php function but then I don't know how to change the color of the text...

Here is the console output :

```
0
1
11.17
2
3
12.90
4
5
12.90
6
```

The complete values are : 12.73 12.90 11.17 22.90 12.90 14.90 **12.90** 12.90
The one in bold is the one displayed in red.

[Here is the rendered HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqNZW.jpg)
And the code :

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rang</th>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Prix(€)</th>
                        <th >Description</th>
                        <th>Précisions d'achat</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td><a href="">Twisty - AHS</a></td>
                                <td class="prix">12.73</td>
                                <td>Twisty le clown dans la saison 4 d'American Horror Story</td>
                                <td>/</td>
                            </tr>12.73<tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td><a href="">Agent Smith - Matrix</a></td>
                                <td class="prix">12.90</td>
                                <td>L'agent Smith dans Matrix</td>
                                <td>Prendre la figurine de l'agent Smith</td>
                            </tr>12.90<tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td><a href="">Finn - Adventure Time</a></td>
                                <td class="prix">11.17</td>
                                <td>Finn dans Adventure Time</td>
                                <td>Frais de port gratuit. Sur Amazon</td>
                            </tr>11.17<tr>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td><a href="">Titan Colossal - SNK</a></td>
                                <td class="prix">22.90</td>
                                <td>Le Titan Colossal de l'anime Shingeki No Kyojin. Figurine plus grande que d'hab donc prix + élevé</td>
                                <td>/</td>
                            </tr>22.90<tr>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td><a href="">Marty McFly - BTTF</a></td>
                                <td class="prix">12.90</td>
                                <td>Marty Mc Fly dans la trilogie Retour vers le futur</td>
                                <td>/</td>
                            </tr>12.90<tr>
                                <td>6</td>
                                <td><a href="">The Dude - TBL</a></td>
                                <td class="prix">14.90</td>
                                <td>Le Duc du film The Big Lebowski</td>
                                <td>/</td>
                            </tr>14.90<tr>
                                <td>7</td>
                                <td><a href="">Wall-E</a></td>
                                <td class="prix">12.90</td>
                                <td>Wall-E du film Disney éponyme</td>
                                <td>/</td>
                            </tr>12.90<tr>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td><a href="">Tim The Enchanter - HG</a></td>
                                <td class="prix">12.90</td>
                                <td>Tim l'Enchanteur du film Sacré Graal des Monty Python</td>
                                <td>Prendre Tim l'Enchanteur. Celui avec les cornes et le lapin</td>
                            </tr>12.90                  </table>
                <script>
                    var prix = new Array;
                    prix[0] = document.getElementsByClassName('prix');
                    var i = 0;
                    var cheapest = 0;
                    while(i< 7){
                        console.log(i);
                        if (Number(prix[0][i].innerHTML) > Number(prix[0][i+1].innerHTML)){
                            cheapest = prix[0][i+1];
                            console.log(cheapest.innerHTML);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    cheapest.style.color = 'red';

                </script>
```

If anyone could help me that would be awesome. And tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Can you include rendered `html` at Question? There appear to be two `12.90` values? Which should have `color` set to `"red"`?

Comment: Well, the `11.17` is supposed to be red. I'll put a screen on my question.

Comment: _"Well, the 11.17 is supposed to be red"_ Why would `11.17` be red, and not `12.90`?  
Can you include actual text of rendered html at Question?

Comment: Yes, that was just testing, the color is not really important for the moment. Oh yeah, of course (I'm so dumb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.slice()` to convert `HTMLCollection` to an array, `Array.prototype.map()` to return `.innerHTML` of elements as an array; `Math.min()`, `Math.max()`, `Array.prototype.indexOf()` to select element from `HTMLColloection` at index where greastest or least number is `.innerHTML`

```
var prix = document.getElementsByClassName("prix");
// added `+` operator to convert string to number
var n = [].slice.call(prix).map(function(el) {return +el.innerHTML});
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, n);
var maxIndex = n.indexOf(max);
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, n);
var minIndex = n.indexOf(min);
prix[maxIndex].style.color = "green";
prix[minIndex].style.color = "red";
```

Comment: I get that in the console : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` So `prix` might be null

Comment: @Von_Kavalier Is `js` at post called within `window.onload = function() {}` ? Or, after `DOM` is loaded?

Comment: Hum... I lack knowledge in js... How do I do that ? :/

Comment: @Von_Kavalier Added `+` operator before `el.innerHTML` to return number from `.map()` which should correct `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` by returning correct index instead of `-1` jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/93cxe6p2/

Comment: OMG ! Works perfectly.. Thank you so much. Sad I didn't find it myself but the answer is here at least :) Thanks